# get id of parent from a child

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm adding drag and drop to a child component and I want to get the id of the parent component in the dragstart event so the drag operation will know where the component originated from. Is there a way to do that with the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the parent node of the target of the event.

`event.target.parentNode.id`

Easy example with click event
HTML:

```
<p id="a">
  <button id="button">my parrent has ID "a"</button>
</p>
```

JS:

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.parentNode.id) // this should be "a"
})
```